# How Secure is the danilop/LambdAuth AWS Lambda Github Project?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

My team and I have been building our sales listing app for months, and it is now in beta and has many users. We are close to implementing the following LambdAuth example project (https://github.com/danilop/LambdAuth) which is an AWS sample, to provide our users a way to register and log in, but are concerned about potential security issues, as our users accounts may contain sensitive information. The described encryption is 'Passwords are not saved in clear in the database, but "salted" (via HMAC-SHA1) using a dedicated, random salt for each password.'.

Is this sufficient enough security for our large user base? Would it be prone to hacking? Does further encryption work need to be done in addition to this project to provide a reasonable amount of password security to users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am the author of the project. I can confirm it has never been checked by a security specialist, and my purpose was more to give an idea of how to build a serverless application, than to use it in a production environment. My suggestion is to look at the new Cognito User Pools, launched a few months ago, that are a complete managed service with much more features:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools.html

Comment: Thank you for your response! The reason I was looking to use your project over Cognito is because I want to have developer authenticated authorities, which don't come straight with Cognito.

Comment: If I understood your requirement correctly, you can manage users with Cognito User Pools (or an external authentication such as Twitter, Facebook, or any provider supporting OpenID Connect or SAML) and then have access to developer authenticated identities. If you'd like to use my framework, please double check it with a security expert.